# Check whether a number is a sum of two prime numbers

Tags: java, arrays, primes

The problem is to check a random number `n` can be the sum of 2 random prime numbers. For example,

> if n=34 the possibilities can be (3+31), (5+29), (17+17)...

So far I have managed to save prime numbers to the array, but have no clue how I could check, if `n` is the sum of 2 prime numbers.

This is part of my code:

```
public static void primeNumbers(int n) {
    int i = 0, candidate = 2, countArray = 0, countPrime = 0;
    boolean flag = true;

    while (candidate <= n) {
        flag = true;
        for (i = 2; i < candidate; i++) {
            if ((candidate % i) == 0) {
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag) {
            countPrime++;
        }
        candidate++;
    }
    int[] primeNumbers = new int[countPrime];


    while (candidate <= n) {
        flag = true;
        for (i = 2; i < candidate; i++) {
            if ((candidate % i) == 0) {
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag) {
            primeNumbers[countArray] = candidate;
        }
        candidate++;
        countArray++;
    }

    for (i = 0; i <= primeNumbers.length; i++) {

    }
}
```

First I counted how many prime numbers are between 1-n so I can declare and initialize my array for prime numbers. Then I save prime numbers to the array.  But now I have no idea how I could check if `n` is the sum of 2 prime numbers.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want to find two primes that sum a natural number N if they exist or check if there do exist a pair of primes?

Comment: All primes, except 2, are odd.  Some odd n, such as 27, cannot be the sum of two primes because n-2 is not prime and two other primes will sum to an even number.  All even n >= 4 in any reasonably computable range are known to be the sum of two primes: see the Goldbach Conjecture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you already have list of "prime numbers less than the given number", It is a very easy task to check if two prime numbers can sum to given number.

```
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){

    int firstNum = array[i];
    int secondNum = givenNum - firstNum;

    /* Now if it is possible to sum up two prime nums to result into given num, secondNum should also be prime and be inside array */

    if(ArrayUtils.contains(array, secondNum)){
        System.out.println("Yes, it is possible. Numbers are "+ firstNum + " and " + secondNum);
    }
}
```

EDIT: [ArrayUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html) is part of Apache Commons Lang library
You can however use [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead to use contains method.

Comment: What about `givenNum = 1234567890`? How long does it take? You'd better use a sorted array of primes and `Arrays.binarySearch` (though still not really fast).

Comment: Yes, i didn't thought about that. Binary search should be used to find if 2nd num is there in array or not. +1 for improvement.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to check all prime numbers from 1 to the given number or you don't even need an array.

Algorithm one can be;

> First of all write a function that checks whether a given number is prime. 
>   Split the number into two parts, 0 and the remaining value(the number itself). Now start decreasing the number part by 1 and start adding 1 to 0 simultaneously. Stop when the number part which we are decreasing becomes 0 or both the parts are prime numbers.

Another algorithm can be like this;(It is similar to the accepted answer)

> Start subtracting prime numbers from the given number starting from 2.Check whether the subtraction is also prime.
>   The time you get the subtraction as a prime number, stop , you have got the two prime numbers that sum up to the given number.